# How to prevent search bots to call API every time

Tags: php, cookies, geolocation, http-headers

I am using ipinfodb API via PHP, where I get geolocation response in JSON and store in a cookie. I am using cookie so that next time when visitor access the site, there will no need to call API again, as ipinfodb API restrict more than two API calls per second. All is working very well, but I am stuck and confused with one thing.

When I fetch as GoogleBot in Google webmaster tools, I got this header response -

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.12.2
Date: Fri, 06 Jul 2018 11:40:02 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: location=US; expires=Sat, 06-Jul-2019 11:40:02 GMT; path=/; httponly
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Expires: Fri, 06 Jul 2018 11:40:01 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
```

I know this response is right and working fine, IPinfodb data like country code has been stored in cookie as "location=US".

But, is this mean, during googlebots (or other bots) crawling or fetching my site, will API called every time?, because as I know cookie cannot be stored at googlebot browsers, so every time an expensive API call will be made. So, first question is:

1. API will be called every time when googlebot crawl my site?
2. Or some how, bots do not call API, then how the response store in cookie?
3. Or bots call API once only as normal user?
4. How can I prevent Googlebot to call API on every visit?

Answer (score 0):

You're inherently requiring the client's participation here for your server not to run afoul of an external API's terms of use. That is rather untenable by design. Also, while this may reduce the number of API calls per individual user, once you have more than two simultaneous visitors you're back to the same issue. Your current strategy makes it *less likely* to hit the limit, but it far from solves the problem.

To do this properly, your server should cache API results internally. So your server remembers the API answer for a specific IP, instead of you requiring the client to remember it for you. memcache or Redis or something along those lines would be the most appropriate kind of storage. This way the server could also keep track of when it last called the API, and throttle itself to avoid going over the allowed limit. Not to mention that you deduplicate work for different clients from the same IP.

Even more properly, you may want to install a geolocation database on your server and avoid external API calls altogether.

Comment: Thank you, but my question unanswered like API will be called every time when googlebot crawl my site?

Comment: If the client (here: googlebot) does not send the cookie, then yes, you're calling the API every time, which is why I'm explaining that it's the wrong approach to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @deceze that really you need to change your approach, there are much better ways of doing this.

However, as you are calling the API in PHP and your specific goal is not to call it for the Googlebot it's easy enough to put a band aid over.

I needed to put some geographical restrictions on access to a site but didn't want to block the Googlebot so I got hold of a list of their IP addresses it uses. I'm a nice guy so I'll share, they are in CIDR format so you'll have to fix that. Then you just tell your script not to call the API if it comes from one of these.

```
64.233.160.0/19
66.102.0.0/20
66.249.64.0/19
72.14.192.0/18
74.125.0.0/16
209.85.128.0/17
216.239.32.0/19
54.187.174.169/32
54.187.205.235/32
54.187.216.72/32
54.241.31.99/32
54.241.31.102/32
54.241.34.107/32
50.18.212.157/32
50.18.212.223/32
52.25.214.31/32
52.26.11.205/32
52.26.14.11/32
52.8.19.58/32
52.8.8.189/32
54.149.153.72/32
54.187.182.230/32
54.187.199.38/32
54.187.208.163/32
54.67.48.128/32
54.67.52.245/32
54.68.165.206/32
54.68.183.151/32
107.23.48.182/32
107.23.48.232/32
```